# Fixed point of a function whose image is different to its domain.

Tags: order-theory, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Take a unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ be a continuous path from $[a,0]$ to $[0,b]$ where $0\le a,b < 1$ are constants. So we can think of $\gamma$ as cutting the square into two pieces as per the graph below.
[image: cutting the square]

Now let $f \colon [0,1]^2\to[0,1]^2$ be a continuous function with the property that $f(\gamma(t)) = 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Let $\le$ denote the element-wise partial order on $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and note that $f(\gamma(t)) \le \gamma(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1].$ **I want to prove that $f$ has a fixed point when its domain is restricted to the set** $$\Gamma = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon (x,y) \le \gamma(t) \text{ for some } t \in [0,1]\}.$$
If $f(\Gamma) \subseteq \Gamma,$ there is likely some standard fixed point theorem we can apply (perhaps Lefschetz?). But if $f(\Gamma) \not\subseteq \Gamma$ then we run into problems.

Intuitively, if we have that $f(x,y)$ is outside of $\Gamma$ for some $(x,y)$ then it must be that $f(x,y) < \gamma(t)$ for some $t$. But since $f(\gamma(t))> \gamma(t),$ as we move away from the line traced out by $\gamma$ and towards the origin, there must be some point where the inequality "swaps", i.e. a fixed point!

Is there a fixed point theorem I can use here to prove this? Or perhaps the intuition is misleading and there is not necessarily a fixed point (or we need more structure on the problem)?

This is the simplest version I could write down of a more general problem which can be posed in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ so any solution which offers a natural generalization to $n$ dimensions is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Here's my idea. For each point on $\gamma(t)$ consider the line segment $\theta\gamma(t)$ for $\theta \in [0,1]$. We can think about the image of $f$ when we "pull in" the entire frontier $\gamma(t)$ towards $(0,0)$. Fix some $t$. Then there is is some smallest $\theta$ such that $f(\theta\gamma(t)) = \theta\gamma(t^{'})$ for some $t^{'} \in [0,1]$. If $t^{'} = t,$ then we're done– $f(\theta\gamma(t))$ is a fixed point. Otherwise, we can trace out a closed path of points such that for each point $p$ on the path, $f(p)$ is some other point on the path. Then use the fixed point property.

Comment: I'm tempted to restrict the doman of $f$ to $Z = f(\Gamma) \cap f(f(\Gamma)) \cap f(f(f(\Gamma))) \cap \cdots$ (or its closure perhaps), so that one might be able to apply a fixed-point theorem to $f\colon Z\to Z$.

Comment: I like this idea but I'm not sure $Z$ is necessarily contained in $\Gamma$. I might be able to put a bit more structure on the problem though and solve it with this idea. Will see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant define $Z = \Gamma \cap f(\Gamma) \cap \cdots$.

Comment: Yep this is exactly the right idea. $Z$ should be topologically equivalent to a closed disk (at least for the functions I have in mind), then we can use Brouwer. I'll see if I can write up a proof and post an answer to the question.